# HTTPS outbound connector in Mule with .pfx file

Tags: https, mule, keystore

I have a password protected `.pfx` file which contains a certificate & private key. I can't open that because my Client can not provide the password for it.

This certificate is needed at the destination endpoint for OAuth validation.
I have to use this in my mule HTTPS outbound connector. 
I tried adding the `.pfx` file to Java Key Store (`.jks`) using Keystore Explorer, but this doesn't work because it's asking for the password, which I don't have.

**So, How can I proceed with this?**

Comment: Not sure without Username and Password it can be used. Since you are calling the service which need to trust you to give response for your request. Provider need to trust You since you are using certificate in HTTP outbound Component.

Comment: Yes, true. Is there any way to extract private key or certificate from it?